# Creating a table with a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a table using VBA:

My code:

```
Sub MakeTablesDynamic()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'This hides the visual process and speeds up
                                    'the execution
Dim tablerng As Range
Dim tablename As String
Dim FirstTableRow As Integer
Dim LastTableRow As Integer

tablename = Right(Cells(7, 1).Value, 25)
FirstTableRow = 12
LastTableRow = 18
Set tablerng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(FirstTableRow, 2), Cells(LastTableRow, LastColumn))

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(tablerng), , xlYes).Name = tablename
```

However when I run this code, I get the following error:

Run-time error '1004':

Method 'Range' of object '_Global' Failed

I know I could make make the code simpler by just saying

```
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$12:$G$18"), , xlYes).Name = tablename
```

but I want to table name and tablerng to be able to change if I want to insert this code within a for loop.

Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got `Range(tablerng)`. You're asking it to create a range of a range. As you've already declared `tablerng` as a range you can just simply use `tablerng`

```
Sub MakeTablesDynamic()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'This hides the visual process and speeds up
                                    'the execution
Dim tablerng As Range
Dim tablename As String
Dim FirstTableRow As Integer
Dim LastTableRow As Integer

tablename = Right(Cells(7, 1).Value, 25)
FirstTableRow = 12
LastTableRow = 18
Set tablerng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(FirstTableRow, 2), Cells(LastTableRow, LastColumn))

ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, tablerng, , xlYes).Name = tablename
```